# Cookie aren't saved

Tags: php, cookies

I need to save a cookie, I'm trying to do this with `setcookie` function, I did:

```
$selector = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
$token = random_bytes(33);
$expires = time() + 864000;

setcookie(
    'remember',
    $selector . ":" . base64_encode($token),
    $expires,
    '/',
    'http://webserver/myapp/',
    true,
    true
);
```

in the browser there is no cookie saved, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setcookie(
    'remember',
    $selector . ":" . base64_encode($token),
    $expires,
    '/myapp/', // Cookie at this folder path only
    'webserver', // This should be set to the domain the cookie is valid on
    False, // Set to false if you are not using ssl
    true
);
```

Some of your settings are wrong. I've corrected can you try?

Comment: U can try using webserver but the folder path and domains are 2 different options. Pls see the example code where I put /myapp/ before the domain